# Set httpContext user.identity.name in test

Tags: testing, .net-core, automated-tests, httpcontext

I'm writing some tests(not unit tests, so I don't have access to the controllers) and one of the api calls keeps failing because HttpContext.User.Identity.Name is null. How can I set this property inside one of my tests? Btw , this is .Net Core 3.1.

Comment: What test framework are you using? If these aren’t unit tests, I assume they are then integration tests?

Comment: Yeah, they are integration tests using MSTest.